# Unknown Variable ‘$L$’ encountered in equation

Tags: proof-explanation

I was going through S.L. Loney’s Plane Trigonometry-Part 1.

I encountered this equation over here :

$$ \sin{B} = \frac{b}{c}$$

Where $B$ is an angle of a Triangle $ABC$, $b$ and $c$ respective sides opposite to angles $B$ and $C$. ($c$ - hypotenuse , triangle is right angled)

Now , the problem arises when : the equation takes form -

$$L \sin{B} = 10 + \log{b} - \log{c}$$

I know he is taking $\log$ on both sides, but I really don’t know what ‘$L$’ is for and how $10$ came into the situation. Kindly help. Is he taking $\log$ to the base of $10$ or $e$? Kindly help, I really cannot sort how ‘$L$’ came into the situation.

Comment: You'll need to give more context if you want help understanding this. No one can guess the meaning of a variable without context.

Comment: Can it be a typo and $L$ be actually $\log$?

Comment: @Patricio no it isn’t . I’ve seen this in other proofs by S.L. Loney too in the same book.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the notation is explained on [pp.166-67](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.86278/page/n185/mode/2up).

Comment: thanks for your help !